# How do I replace a formula to stay on a specific cell in vba when the sheet it references updates

Tags: excel, vba

I've been playing with this code for the past week and have gotten it to 90% of what I want it to do.

Rows 14 and 15 were manually selected when it comes to the formulas and are referencing subtotal cells on the Media Plan sheet. These are correct.

This is the code in a nutshell:
"Insert new vendor" will copy from "ref sheet" defined cells "New_Vendor" it is 19 rows including subtotal row with formulas.
It then creates a new row in "P & L sheet" with the same formatting from the above cell.
It will then insert into the new row formulas that reference the cells from subtotal row in "Media Plan sheet"

This all works great the first time.



The issue is when you run the macro a second time.
Because I used offset from a defined name it updates the Vendor row to read the wrong line.

How do I stop this?

Is there a way to have the code run multiple times with each iteration referencing the correct new rows?

In Image 1
Rows 16 and 17 were created using the Macro code

![Image shows formulas][1]

![Name Manager with Defined Names][2]

[Source Data][3]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

````
Sub Insert_New_VendorPNL()
'
' Insert_New_Vendor Macro
'

'Screen won't update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Select from hidden Ref sheet rows 13:23 copy and paste to
'Media Plan sheet above Grand Total Row

    Sheets("Ref").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="New_Vendor"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
'Go to Media Plan Sheet, Select Grand Total Row insert new rows
    Sheets("Media Plan").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="Grand_Total_Row"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'Go to P&L sheet insert new row above Total
    Application.Goto Reference:="PnL_Total_Row"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'Insert formulas
'A Insert Publisher Name
    Application.Goto Reference:="PnLTotalA"                     'select PnLTotalA Cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select                             'Go one row up
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_Publisher,-1,0)"    'Insert Formula =OFFSET("Named Reference, 1 row up, 0 column change)

'C Client Gross (revenue)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select                              'Select cell to same row 2 columns to the right
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"                      'Inserts Formula =R (Row Null)C[1 Column to the right]/0.85)
'D Client Net (Revenue)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ClientNet,-1,0)"
'E Buyer Gross Budget Assigned
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"
'F Buyer Net Budget Assigned
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ETNegotiatedNet,-1,0)"
'G Station Gross Purchased
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
'H Cash % Purchased
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ETPercentCash,-1,0)"
'I Trade % Purchased
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ETPercentTrade,-1,0)"
'J Net Cash Cost
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ETCashCost,-1,0)"
'K Gross Trade Amount
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"
'L Net Trade Cost
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ETTotalTrade,-1,0)*OFFSET(MP_GT_ETTradeFactor,-1,0)"
'M Net ET Cost
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-1]"
'N Net Media Spread
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]-RC[-1]"
'O Media Spread Index
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-11]"
'P Est. Trade Credit Usage
'Q *Trade Credit Usage
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*RC[-13]"
'R Estimated ERT Net Profit
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]-RC[-1]"
'S ERT Net Profit %
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-15]"
'T Gross Media Margin
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/(RC[-16]-RC[-3])"

'go to and select Grand Total Row
'    Application.Goto Reference:="Grand_Total_Row"


End Sub```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZXAG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRfEV.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO3ts.png
````

Comment: Edit your question and show how the source data is layed out. We can work from there

Comment: You should not be using `.Select` or `.Selection` for any of this. The macro recorder returns that when you do things because it takes your actions literally instead of translating them to the actual underlying data changes. You can refer to a cell or a set of cells or a named range directly and change attributes like the value without any need to select them as you would if were using Excel normally. I'll show you an example of how to fix that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fix in the end.

Added this declared variable just above the formula insert after the create new sheets as it then allowed me to create the right formula referencing the correct row, instead of relying on offset which would then update each time I ran the code causing the subtotal row to duplicate.

`Dim cntA As Long
 cntA = Sheets("Media Plan").Range("cntA")`

Also created a new defined cell in Column A that is cntA with the formula =row()-1 which is in the same row as the Grand Total row

Changed the formula from `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=offset(MP_GT_Publisher,-1,0)"`

To this
`ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Formula = "=" & mp & "H" & cntA`

Here is the full code

```
Sub NewVendorRevised()
    Dim plWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Set plWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("P&L")
    Dim mp As String
    mp = "'Media Plan'!"

    cpyRow = Sheets("Media Plan").Range("Grand_Total_Row").Row 'read the row into a variable

    Sheets("Media Plan").Rows(cpyRow).Resize(19).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the 19 rows
    Sheets("Ref").Range("New_Vendor").Copy Sheets("Media Plan").Cells(cpyRow, 1) 'Copy the reference cells
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("P&L").Range("PnL_Total_Row").EntireRow.Resize(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Dim cntA As Long
    cntA = Sheets("Media Plan").Range("cntA")
    'Formula is input into active sheet P&L using defined name PnLTotalA
        'A Publisher
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("P&L").Activate
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Formula = "=" & mp & "H" & cntA
        'C Client Gross Rev
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"
        'D Client Net Rev
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Formula = "=" & mp & "T" & cntA
        'E Buyer Gross Budget Assigned
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"
        'F Buyer Net Budget Assigned
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 5).Formula = "=" & mp & "V" & cntA
        'G Station Gross Purchased
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
        'H Cash % Purchased
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Formula = "=" & mp & "W" & cntA
        'I Trade % Purchased
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).Formula = "=" & mp & "X" & cntA
        'J Net Cash Cost
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 9).Formula = "=" & mp & "Y" & cntA
        'K Gross Trade Amount
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85"
        'L Net Trade Cost
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 11).Formula = "=" & mp & "Z" & cntA & "*" & mp & "AA" & cntA
        'M Net ET Cost
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-1]"
        'N Net Media Spread
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]-RC[-1]"
        'O Media Spread Index
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-11]"
        'P Est. Trade Credit Usage
        'Q *Trade Credit Usage
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 16).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*RC[-13]"
        'R Estimated ERT Net Profit
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]-RC[-1]"
        'S ERT Net Profit %
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-15]"
        'T Gross Media Margin
        plWS.Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 19).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/(RC[-16]-RC[-3])"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you copy the range of cells from the hidden sheet:

```
Sheets("Ref").Select
Application.Goto Reference:="New_Vendor"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
```

Here is where you insert them with the value into the Media Plan sheet:

```
Sheets("Media Plan").Select
Application.Goto Reference:="Grand_Total_Row"
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

And here is where you insert the corresponding row in P&L:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="PnL_Total_Row"
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

All you need to do is this:

```
cpyRow = Sheets("Media Plan").Range("Grand_Total_Row").Row 'read the row into a variable
Sheets("Media Plan").Rows(cpyRow).Resize(19).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the 19 rows
Sheets("Ref").Range("New_Vendor").Copy Sheets("Media Plan").Cells(cpyRow, 1) 'copy the reference cells
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Sheets("P&L").Range("PnL_Total_Row").EntireRow.Resize(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the row, you shouldn't need to specify origin because it defaults to left or above

That should be help you see how to apply it the rest of your code. Also note that you want to refer to a worksheet with its `.CodeName` (that is the name that appears before parentheses in editor) instead of the `.Name` since that allows you to rename the worksheet in the tab without having to update code. So replace `Sheets("Ref")` with `reference` for example.

Comment: I can see the advantage of writing the code the way you did. I'm just struggling to understand how it will work with the formulas.
I started to rewrite it and am not sure if I should be writing each line as

`code With Worksheets("P&L").Range("PnLTotalA").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_Publisher,-1,0)" 'A
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).Formula2R1C1 = "=RC[1]/0.85" 'C
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(MP_GT_ClientNet,-1,0)" 'D
End With
`
or as just one line item. i couldn't figure out how to do it - the with